# Laptop goes to sleep if i close the lid during startup?

Tags: suspend, shutdown

I just discovered something weird today. On my system running Ubuntu 15.10, I have set that closing the lid doesn't put my laptop to sleep. But if I close the lid while my pc is starting up or shutting down, it goes to sleep. Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

The setting only affects the logged in user. To set it system wide you need to edit the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
and modify the line:

```
"#HandleLidSwitch=suspend"
```

to

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Then either reboot or use:

```
sudo restart systemd-logind
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

For the newer systemd.